# Access to a Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I have a problem with accessing a sandbox, I recently got hired to a new company and other admin has many sandboxes, with classes that I need to upload to production,

I don't have access to that sandbox and I can't refresh because I will lose the new classes. Is there a way gain access without refreshing the sandboxes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix this is to have someone already in that Sandbox to grant access to you. They can log in, go in to Setup to [refresh license counts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.overview_licenses_and_sandbox.htm&type=5), and then add you as a user. If the previous admin is not available, you may be able to work with Technical Support to gain access.